# Test suite runs in two batches with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In a Rails 4.0.2 app, when running `rake test` with MiniTest, the tests run in batches, instead of reporting aggregate pass/fail numbers for all tests. That is, the model tests run as one batch, and the integration tests as another. My output from a single invocation of `rake test` looks like this:

```
Loaded Suite test,test/integration,test/models
# All the model tests run and print their output here
18 tests, 18 passed, 0 failures, 0 errors, 1 skips, 40 assertions

Loaded Suite test,test/integration,test/models
# All the integration tests run and print their output here
5 tests, 5 passed, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips, 24 assertions
```

This does *not* occur when I run `rake test:all`. I tested this with the built-in MiniTest runner and the Turn runner. Both exhibit this behavior.

Is it intentional that MiniTest splits the tests into batches when running `rake test` but not `rake test:all`?

I did a `bundle update`, and none of my testing gems have a version constraint, so I believe everything is up to date. Gem versions:

- Rails 4.0.2
- MiniTest 4.7.5
- MiniTest Rails 0.9.2

Comment: that's strange! are the files in the suite always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional in that this is how the rails testing tasks work in rails 3.x. The minitest-rails library overrides the tasks and gives you the old behavior. An upcoming release of minitest-rails will change this and work similar to the rails 4 tasks work.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very straightforward answer.